# override firefox components

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, components, overriding

I was wondering if anyone knows how to override firefox components. I have tried to override the `nsHelperAppDlg.js` using the manifest file but it didn't seem to work. This is what I did:

> override resource:///components/nsHelperAppDlg.js myextension/components/nsHelperAppDlg.js

I've also tried to modify that file straight from the omni.ja file but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

P.S I'm using Firefox 10.0.2

Answer (score 2):

With the manifest you can only override `chrome://` URLs. XPCOM components aren't accessed via `chrome://` URLs but rather their contract IDs (`@mozilla.org/helperapplauncherdialog;1` in this case). But I suspect that you don't really want to replace the component - it is rarely a good idea. You probably want to override or overlay the "unknown file type" dialog. The URL of this dialog is `chrome://mozapps/content/downloads/unknownContentType.xul` and you can override it, like this:

> override chrome://mozapps/content/downloads/unknownContentType.xul chrome://myextension/content/unknownContentType.xul